# A condition for two operators to commute, help with a proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator

In my quantum mechanics textbook (chapter regarding central potentials), it is said that: if $L$ (angular momentum operator, but could by any operator) acts only on the variables $ \theta, \phi $, and if any operator (say $H$ with a central potential $V = V(r)$ ) acts only on the variable $r$, then $[L,H]= 0$.

I see it that it is true if we take a test function of the form $f(r,\theta , \phi) = f_1 (r) f_2 (\theta , \phi)$, but why does it work for any $ f(r,\theta , \phi)$, i.e. not separated.

How does one prove this?

In general:
Define the set of variables $X = (x_1 , x_2 ,..., x_n) $ and two operators $A,B$ such that they act on different subsets of $X$. Is $[A,B] = 0$?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, but [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker ok!

Comment: Can you see it is true on a linear combination of such factorized test functions, so, then, even an infinite one?

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, if you mean to write $f = \Sigma c_i f_1 f_2$  . But in the book , nothing like this is mentioned... It just says because they (the operators) act on different variables $\implies$ they commute.

Comment: So you expand an arbitrary function in terms of factorized functions and you are done. You are meant to *see* it.  I'm sorry, but it is truly bad form to foist specific ill-chosen books on the reading audience here to shadow-box with...

Comment: @CosmasZachos did not mean to shadow box , I thought it would be good to mention where I saw the problem (I also originally posted a screenshot, but removed it...)

Comment: Another way you could prove it is to use the fact that you are operating on the space of test functions $f(r,\theta,\phi)$, plus a little physics, to say that $H$ should have the form of a local differential operator, eg $H=\sum_{n=0}^N f_n(r) \partial_r^n$, and $L=\sum_{i=0}^I \sum_{j=0}^J g_{i,j}(\theta,\phi) \partial_\theta^i \partial_\phi^j$ for finite $N, I, J$. Then it should be pretty clear that $[H, L]=0$, since partial derivatives commute and $\partial_r g_{ij}(\theta,\phi)=\partial_\theta f_n(r)=\partial_\phi f_n(r)=0$.